# Toggle divs based on checkbox values regex

Tags: jquery, regex

I'm trying to toggle divs based on checkbox value by regex

I put unique id as `data-row-id` and using that value I'm trying to hide and show divs

Here is my regex

```
new RegExp("^" + $("input[type='checkbox'].filter-industry:checked").map(function () { 
  return $(this).data("rowId"); 
}).get().join("|") + "$");
```

then i do this

```
$("div.industry-ri-box").each(function () { 
  var $this = $(this); 
  $this[rowIds.source !== "0" 
    && rowIds.test($this.data("rowId")) ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut"](); });
```

it seems work perfects but for some combination it messing up. I know something is wrong with the regex but couldn't figure it out

*i got this far by following a stackoverflow answer unfortunately I couldn't find it for reference sorry about that.*

here is the [sample codepen](https://codepen.io/gayan85/pen/RLRZZw) for the that

Comment: Basically, `Accounting` breaks it. We have to find the problem in that one

Comment: yeah accounting breaks it but it just random

Comment: You also have console errors

Comment: I've been testing it in the console. I believe the problem is that the 1, which is the id of Accounting, also matches the rest that start with a 1.

Comment: By the way, I wouldn't use regex for such a thing. There are many more better and more intuitive ways to do what you want, than matching the ids with a regex. It would still work well, but it's just not a good way

Comment: agreed since this is simple thing i don't feel to write many line of code for that regex will reduce all pain to two line

Comment: @GayanRanasinghe Is this what you want https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZXOJdq

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen no it's not. Putting the 1 at the end won't solve anything if he changes the ids, it will just make anything with a 1 at the end match the regex, instead of anything with a 1 at the start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The accounting breaks the regexp because its id is 1. So if 1 is anywhere in the id, for example 18 it will be displayed.

Change the var rowIds row to this, so every number will is surrounded by line begin/end characters (^ and $):

```
var rowIds = new RegExp("^" + $("input[type='checkbox'].filter-industry:checked").map(function () { return $(this).data("rowId"); }).get().join("$|^") + "$");
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding braces around the content of your regex, so instead of it finally being eg: `^5|1|18$` it should be `^(5|1|18)$`

Here's the relevant line:

```
new RegExp("^(" + $("input[type='checkbox'].filter-industry:checked").map(function () { 
    return $(this).data("rowId"); 
}).get().join("|") + ")$");
```

Comment: This would leave the same problem

Comment: Actually, this would give him an even worse problem: It would also match any number containing one of the numbers in the regex, as you don't specify that you want them to be at the start nor at the end of the string

Comment: Sorry, the eg-example didn't have the ^ and $ anchors, even tho the relevant line example had them. With those this should work. Edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use regex for your particular use case.

Something like this – separating the showing-and-hiding of the boxes from the checkbox behavior – feels nicer:

```
$(function() {
  var $industryCheckboxes = $("input[type='checkbox'].filter-industry");
  function updateBoxVisibility() {
    var checkedIds = $industryCheckboxes.filter(":checked")
            .map(function() {
              return $(this).data("rowId");
            })
            .get();
    $("div.industry-ri-box").each(function() {
      var $box = $(this);
      var shouldShow = (checkedIds.includes(0) || checkedIds.includes($box.data("rowId")));
      $box[shouldShow ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
    });
  }
  $industryCheckboxes.on("change", function(e) {
    var $checkbox = $(this);
    if(this.checked) {
      if($checkbox.data("rowId") == "0") {
        $industryCheckboxes.slice(1).prop("checked", false);
      } else {
        $industryCheckboxes.first().prop("checked", false);
      }
    }
    updateBoxVisibility();
  });
});
```